# D3 data table vs DC Data table, which one better with combination of jQuery data table?

Tags: d3.js, datatables, dc.js

Which one(D3/DC) is better to use along with Jquery Data table in terms of performance and features.

For example if we are combining it with DC we are able link with other charts like line, pie and etc. But here the limit of filters are restricted to 32 in DC.

In this way I am expecting the difference between D3 and DC.

Thanks,
Kumar

Comment: Please use the dc.js tag for questions about the charting library - dc is quite something else.

Comment: I don't know of a d3 data table and tbh I'm pretty confused by your question. Please consider editing it if you still need help.